# Logistic regression

Tags: regression, ratio, odds

I want to calculate sex and age adjusted odds ratio (simultaneous adjustment) in addition to 95% CI.
The dependent variable is disease (0 or 1)
The independent variables are age (continuous), sex (0 or 1), and blood sugar (continuous). 
How to calculate the sex and age adjusted odds ratio?
Which one of the tests should be used: multinomial logistic regression or binary logistic regression or another test?

Answer (score 1):

Use binary logistic because your outcome is binary. You can use the R function glm with argument family=binomial to do this. Use age, sex, and blood sugar as the predictors. Exponentiate the coefficient for blood sugar to get the adjusted odds ratio. Do +/- 1.96 * SE (before exponentiating) to get a 95% CI for the adjusted OR.

Logistic regression is also implemented in any other statistical software package if you don't use R.

Best,

Hammond